# Removing a substring including parentheses and dash from other strings in R

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to remove substring `" - Homo sapiens (human)"` from a list of strings using `gsub(.)` function. I think I need to convert it to a regular expression But I do not know how to do it. I appreciate if anyone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It does not work. @lukeA suggested the answer, the point is using "fixed=TRUE" in `gsub(.)` function.

Comment: `()` are metacharacters in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gsub(" - Homo sapiens (human)", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
```

, where `x` contains your character vector.

Comment: OP, can try using `gsub("-.*", "",x)`, but as he didn't show input it's hard to tell if this works.